# How use rails 5.1+ without yarn and webpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, assets

I update my rails app to pass at 5.1.X to day,
but surprise, my config to minify JS and CSS dosn't work anymore...

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(output: {comments: /^!/})
```

> ** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
>   ** Execute yarn:install Yarn executable was not detected in the system. Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
>   ** Execute assets:precompile rake aborted! Uglifier::Error: Invalid assignment

If I comment out the line, it works, but JS is not minified and there is inaccessible on site... like all others assets, but there are present in cache in /public folder... I don't understand why asset pipeline doesn't work now?!

So how can I stay with classic asset pipeline and disabled yarn call ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this and as it is a very new issue, I would think about posting also an issue on Uglifier github page. I do not understand why Uglifier is causing problem to yarn as asset pipeline files are in `app` while `yarn` will keep them in `node_modules`.

I believe the issue here is that `Uglifier` already works on `production` files (in fact that is a production setting) and the asset pipeline will be working with yarn. You can require files in your `application.js` and `.scss` from the yarn `node_modules` folder, they will be included in your assets.

in this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#loading-rails) you can find out how rails requires the different components

```
  active_record/railtie
  action_controller/railtie
  action_view/railtie
  action_mailer/railtie
  active_job/railtie
  action_cable/engine
  rails/test_unit/railtie
  sprockets/railtie
```

I gave a very quick look at this, could not find anything relevant to `yarn` in `railties/lib/rails/all.rb` so I decided to search the `rails` repository for `yarn` keyword and find out [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8e9e94391902b854662ba5eb06cc006cc4e85212/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/initializers/assets.rb.tt)

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
<%- unless options[:skip_yarn] -%>
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
<%- end -%>

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
```

so maybe you should [search for this `option\[:skip_yarn\]`?](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=options%5B%3Askip_yarn%5D&type=) 
I wish you good luck

Fabrizio

Comment: in fact, when I comment the line (about Uglifier) in config, precompile works, assets are generated in /public folder, but there are all  inaccessible on site... I don't understand why asset pipeline doesn't works now?!
I don't have yarn installed, so I search solution without use it... :skip_yarn option seem to be used for no include node_module, but I don't have this on my app.